# Selecting the MIN(date) and the MAX(date) with the MAX(date) Freight Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I need the MIN(Orderdate) and MAX(Orderdate) with the MAX(Orderdate) Freight values.

I've tried using a CTE and I am struggling to eliminate duplicate rows for the CustomerID

```
USE Northwind
GO

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.customerID,
    MAX(b.OrderDate) AS LastOrder,
    MIN(b.OrderDate) AS FirstOrder

    FROM Orders AS b
INNER JOIN Customers AS a 
ON b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
GROUP BY a.CustomerID
)

SELECT CTE.customerID, CTE.FirstOrder, d.OrderDate as LastOrder, d.Freight
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN Orders as d
On CTE.CustomerID = d.CustomerID 
GROUP BY CTE.CustomerID, CTE.FirstOrder, d.Freight, d.OrderDate
HAVING d.OrderDate = MAX(d.OrderDate)
```

I am trying to get these results which should display 89 records.

```
  CustomerID   FirstOrder   LastOrder    Freight
|  ALFKI     | 1997-08-25 | 1998-04-09 |  1.21   |
|  ANATR     | 1996-09-18 | 1998-03-04 |  39.92  |
|  ANTON     | 1996-11-27 | 1998-01-28 |  58.43  |
|  AROUT     | 1996-11-15 | 1998-04-10 |  33.80  |
|  BERGS     | 1996-08-12 | 1998-03-04 |  151.52 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.customerID,
      MAX(o.OrderDate) AS LastOrder,
      MIN(o.OrderDate) AS FirstOrder,
      MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN o.freight END) as lastFreight
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.customerID ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Orders o
     ) o
GROUP BY o.CustomerID;
```

Note that you do not appear to need the `Customer` table.  All the information you need is in `Orders` (I doubt you are using `Customer` to remove rows.)

Answer (score 2):

Just to Keep it simple and in line with the question. The Subquery CTE already has the customerID and the LastOrder(Max Order Date). Joining the LastOrder column in CTE to the Order tables OrderDate will give the expected results.

```
and d.OrderDate = CTE.LastOrder
```

Full Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.customerID,
    MAX(b.OrderDate) AS LastOrder,
    MIN(b.OrderDate) AS FirstOrder

    FROM Orders AS b
INNER JOIN Customers AS a 
ON b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
GROUP BY a.CustomerID
)
SELECT CTE.customerID, CTE.FirstOrder, d.OrderDate as LastOrder, d.Freight
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN Orders as d
On CTE.CustomerID = d.CustomerID 
and d.OrderDate = CTE.LastOrder
```